# Multiple transforms UIView

Tags: swift

I want to transform my image view like this:

[image]

I use landscape mode, I want the panda begin at the center vertically from the left, then it will rotate 360 again and again with become bigger and bigger, and go to the center vertically to the right.

[image]

I have tried like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.0, 3.0)
        let rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180*CGFloat(M_PI)/180)
        let translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 100, 0)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, delay: 0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse, .CurveEaseInOut], animations: { () -> Void in
            let mixTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(scale, translate)
            self.imageView.transform = mixTransform
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse, .CurveEaseInOut], animations: { () -> Void in
            self.imageView.transform = rotate
            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your transforms obviously dont fit your requirements.

If you want image to scale proportionally, why you set different scales for X and Y then?

Again, if you want image to move along X axis, why you adjust Y position of it in transforms? Simply fix your transform and you are ready to go.

In particular:

```
let scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.0, 3.0)
...
let translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 400, 0)
```

Comment: I have some trouble with translate and rotate, when I set translate as you said, the panda go to the bottom-mid

Comment: If I delete rotate transform, it goes straight ahead

Comment: it must be something with anchor point of UIView, have you tried to set it to (0.5, 0.5)?

Comment: Please check my update, I use 2 UIView.animate(...). But I want the panda at the beginning don't rotate 360 and it should always rotate during translate to the right.

Comment: Try setting the same duration for both animate methods

Comment: Can you upload a demo project?

Comment: the project is include those code I posted and the panda image in storyboard, I set constrain width = 100, height = 100, center vertically to super view, leading space to super view = 0

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let kRotationAnimationKey = "com.myapplication.rotationanimationkey"

        func rotateView(view: UIView, duration: Double = 1) {
            if view.layer.animationForKey(kRotationAnimationKey) == nil {
                let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")

                rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
                rotationAnimation.toValue = Float(M_PI * 2.0)
                rotationAnimation.duration = duration
                rotationAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity

                view.layer.addAnimation(rotationAnimation, forKey: kRotationAnimationKey)
            }
        }

        func stopRotatingView(view: UIView) {
            if view.layer.animationForKey(kRotationAnimationKey) != nil {
                view.layer.removeAnimationForKey(kRotationAnimationKey)
            }
        }

        var transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 200, 0)
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 3.0, 3.0)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse, .CurveEaseInOut], animations: { () -> Void in
            self.imageView.transform = transform
            rotateView(self.imageView)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }) { (_) -> Void in
               stopRotatingView(self.imageView)
        }
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]